# c# linq change the value of xml element which contains xml tags

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement, setvalue

I tested with the following source xml File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <key name="some text" id="1"/>
    <key name="some text" id="2"/>
    <house id="H1">
        <floor id="F1">
            <room id="R1">Child1<electrics><socket id="C1S1"/></electrics></room>
            <room id="R2">Child2<electrics><socket id="C2S1"/></electrics></room>
        </floor>
    </house>
</root>
```

I would like to copy/clone the complete tag (room id="R1") and paste as last room within floor. At the same time I want to change the tag value of (room id="R1") to "Whatever" and the (socket id) within the (room)-Tag to "new room"

Finaly I want to get the following xml-structure

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <key name="some text" id="1" />
  <key name="some text" id="2" />
  <house id="H1">
    <floor id="F1">
      <room id="R1">Child1<electrics><socket id="C1S1" /></electrics></room>
      <room id="R2">Child2<electrics><socket id="C2S1" /></electrics></room>
      <room id="R1">Whatever<electrics><socket id="new room" /></electrics></room>
    </floor>
  </house>
</root>
```

But I have problems with that. After creating the clone I can not change the value of the new room, without deleting the nested tags. 
The third last comand causes my problem. If you skip that comand you get a nearly perfect clone, but I do not know how to change the value.

Here my c# Code

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace linqxmlTester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private XElement xmlDoc;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            xmlDoc = XElement.Load("house.xml");

            // Select rooms to clone I realy only want to selekt one room, but I have to go over rooms
            IEnumerable<XElement> newRoom = from rooms in xmlDoc.Element ("house")
                                                                .Element ("floor")
                                                                .Elements("room")

                                                    where rooms.ToString().IndexOf("C1S1") > 0

                                                    select rooms;
            // I've selected realy one room in rooms with the following I clone beheind last room
            xmlDoc.Element ("house")
                  .Element ("floor")
                  .Elements("room").Last()
                  .AddAfterSelf(newRoom.First()); // there is only one

            // This worked   :-)

            //But now I want to change socket id value (="C1S1") to something new
            //I select my last created room

            XElement newRoom1 = xmlDoc.Element("house")
                                      .Element("floor")
                                      .Elements("room").Last();

            //within the newRoom1 I search for the attribute id

            foreach (var r in newRoom1.Elements("electrics").Elements("socket"))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("aktValue " + r.Attribute("id").Value);
                r.Attribute("id").Value = "new room";
                Debug.WriteLine("newValue " + r.Attribute("id").Value);
            }

            // this is working too :-)

            // Now I only still have to change the value of my newroom
            // it should be the following code

            Debug.WriteLine("OldValue " + newRoom1.Value); // prints only the value without the embeded xml tags

            newRoom1.SetValue("Whatever"); // this kills the complete xml structure with is embede at the side of the value

            Debug.WriteLine("NewValue " + newRoom1.Value); // prints only the newvalue without the embeded xml tags

            xmlDoc.Save("housenew.xml");
        }
}
}
```

How can I change the value in c# using linq, without deleting an embeded xml structure?

Thanks for your tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to see your `room` element as a node of a tree. Everything below that is a node as well, so in fact, `Child1` is a node (text) and `electrics` is node (element).

Visually represented:

```
* Element: room (with attribute id)
|- Text: Child1
|- Element: electrics
   |- Element: socket (with attribute id)
```

So to get to that text-node (`Child1`), just change the first subnode of `room` like such:

```
newRoom1.Nodes().First().ReplaceWith("Whatever");
```

If you'd change `.Value` of room, you'd be replacing the entire subtree of `room`.

I'd avoid this kind of structure though, if possible. Change the 'Child1' value so that it is either an attribute of room (preferred), or wrap it in a node so that `<room id="1"><description>Child1</description></room>`

Comment: Thank you. ReplaceWith solved my problem.

My example structur was just to simplify where my problem was.
In reality I try to edit an graphml File generated by yed, where I encountered a lot more difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

You select the row that way

```css
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>" +
                "<root>" +
                    "<key name=\"some text\" id=\"1\"/>" +
                    "<key name=\"some text\" id=\"2\"/>" +
                    "<house id=\"H1\">" +
                        "<floor id=\"F1\">" +
                            "<room id=\"R1\">Child1<electrics><socket id=\"C1S1\"/></electrics></room>" +
                            "<room id=\"R2\">Child2<electrics><socket id=\"C2S1\"/></electrics></room>" +
                        "</floor>" +
                    "</house>" +
                "</root>";

            XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Parse(input);
            XElement floor = xmlDoc.Descendants("floor").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement newR1 = new XElement(floor.Elements("room").Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "R1").FirstOrDefault());
            XAttribute socket = newR1.Element("electrics").Element("socket").Attribute("id");
            socket.Value = "new room";
            floor.Add(newR1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XML results

```css
<root>
  <key name="some text" id="1" />
  <key name="some text" id="2" />
  <house id="H1">
    <floor id="F1">
      <room id="R1">Child1<electrics><socket id="C1S1" /></electrics></room>
      <room id="R2">Child2<electrics><socket id="C2S1" /></electrics></room>
      <room id="R1">Child1<electrics><socket id="new room" /></electrics></room>
    </floor>
  </house>
</root>
```

Comment: The selection for the room in this solution is a lot shorter then my one.

But still its not possible to change the value of the newR1 tag. If I add 

newR1.SetValue("Whatever");

before the floor.add all the structure (<electrics><socket id="new room" /></electrics>) becomes deleted.

Comment: I posted the XML results which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: It is nearly the solution I was looking for. I had problems to change the value of the second "Child1" to "Whatever". This is resolved with newR1.Nodes().First().ReplaceWith("Whatever"); But you helped me with the different approach using the ".Where(x => ......) Thanks a lot for that.